# Compass Index Creation

Tags: java, compass-lucene

I am getting errors like

```
Failed to open Lucene reader/searcher; nested exception is  
org.compass.core.engine.SearchEngineException:  
Failed to open index searcher for sub-index [meta]; nested exception is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException:  
/home/test/testrun/target/compass/project/index/meta/segments_dia  
(No such file or directory).
```

Comment: show the code related

Comment: Code means in java or need for configuration files

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the path `/home/test/testrun/target/compass/project/index/meta/segments_dia` from the exception?

[Code from compass](https://github.com/kimchy/compass/blob/master/src/main/src/org/compass/core/lucene/engine/LuceneSearchEngineHighlighter.java) throws this exception if it can't find such directory.

Comment: code only throws the exception.But why its coming.Application running good only and suddenly i got error above mentioned.How can i find and resolve